# Convert an array to string inside an object using Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have an object payload, where one of the key-value pair is an array inside the object. How can I convert that key-value pair to string.

Input:

```
{
   "key1":{
      "sk1":"abc",
      "sk2":12,
      "key2":[
         "aa",
         "bbb",
         "ccc",
         "ddd"
      ]
   }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
   "key1": "sk1: abc, sk2:12, key2: aa,bbb,ccc,ddd"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this kind of problem is resolved by combining a recursive function with pattern matching by type.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun printObject(x) =
    x  match {
            case is String  ->  x
            case is Number -> x as String
            case is Object ->
                x mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key): printObject(value)  ) 
                pluck ((value, key, index) -> key as String ++ ":" ++ value)
                joinBy(",")
            case is Array -> (x map printObject($)) joinBy(",")
            else -> x
    }
---
payload mapObject ($$): printObject($)
```

Output:

```
{
  "key1": "sk1:abc,sk2:12,key2:aa,bbb,ccc,ddd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something quick I have come up with

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var keys=payload.key1 pluck $$
var values=payload.key1 pluck $
fun returnVal(key_index) =  
values[key_index] 
---
key1:(keys map(v0,k0) -> (v0 as String ++ ':' ++ if(typeOf(returnVal(k0)) ~= 'Array') (returnVal(k0) joinBy  ',') else returnVal(k0)  ) ) joinBy  ','
```